# Jquery and Captcha on same page can't get it working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I warn you now very little experience at jquery. My question is this. I have a username and password form. I have Jquery that accesses a php page looks into the database matches the password and user name then echos "yes" or no based off if the input is right then takes me to the next page. Now since this Jquery works on submit I can't figure out how to add a javascript captcha correctly to the page because it wont verify the word. So I'm wondering how to alter or add to this code so that I can first verify the word using javascript then the jquery below. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#login_form").submit(function()
        {
            //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading
            $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
            //check the username exists or not from ajax
        $.post("ajax_login.php",{ user_name:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
            {
              if(data=='yes') //if correct login detail
              {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  //start fading the messagebox
                { 
                  //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                  $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1,
                  function()
                  { 
                     //redirect to secure page
                     document.location='edujob.php';
                  });
                });
              }
              else 
              {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
                { 
                  //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                  $(this).html('incorrect').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                });     
              }

            });
            return false; //not to post the  form physically
        });
        //now call the ajax also focus move from 

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Off-topic: the script's `language` attribute is deprecated. You should use the `type="text/javascript"`, or even better, if you're using the HTML5 doctype just go with a simple `<script>...</script>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side captcha is useless because it can be by-passed by the end-user. I'd recommend you to use a captcha library. For instance, [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) is a very simple and strong server-side library maintained by Google which is easy to implement ([reCAPTCHA PHP Docs](http://code.google.com/intl/es-419/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html)).

Once it is implemented, I'd change the javascript ajax call with this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax_login.php",
  type: "text",
  dataType: "string",
  data: $("#login_form").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    if(data === "yes") {
      // DO SOMETHING
    } else {
      // DO SOMETHING

      // Reload reCAPTCHA
      if(typeof Recaptcha === "object") {
        Recaptcha.reload();
      }

    }
  }
});
```

That's what I think is the best solution.

Comment: I have it implemented but now it goes directly to its verify page instead of first going to the javascript at the top how would I fix this?

Comment: Did you remmeber to add the `return false;` line?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can have a client-side-only captcha, server side has to be involved somehow to match scrambled word with what user entered. If match was happening on client side it would mean that a bot could get access to the original word and pass for human.

What captcha do you use? Any plugin or something home-made?

Comment: jcap there are two javascript plug ins to run it. How would I run a server side captcha?

Comment: jcap is circa 2004 and any more or less sophisticated bot will be able to read it. If you want my advise, you something up to date, like ReCaptcha or Lanap BotDetect (I'm using the latter, free version)